# Binding the Dialog to my angular controller

Tags: metro-ui-css

I am trying to bind a MetroUI modal dialog to an angular controller property. This way I can show and hide the dialog using binding.

DIRECTIVE

```
appMod.directive('showDialog', ['$timeout', function ($timeout): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.showDialog, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    element.show();
                }
                else {
                    element.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="padding20 dialog" id="dialog9" 
     data-role="dialog" data-close-button="true"
     data-overlay="true" data-overlay-color="op-dark" 
     show-dialog="vm.isDialogVisible">
```

This way I can control opening the dialog by setting the vm.isDialogVisible Boolean on my controller.

Problem is that I am trying to update the vm.isDialogVisible attribute when the user closes the dialog (via the close button). Anyone has some ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It is always cool to find your own solution (took me a day :-)). I made a mistake to use the show / hide features of the element. I should have used the data attribute of the element. That way I am able to access the

> onDialogClose

function, which enable me to update the scope. Below my solution

```
appMod.directive(showDialog,  ['$timeout','$parse',function ($timeout, $parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {    
            var e1 = theDialog.data('dialog');

            $timeout(() => {
                e1.options.onDialogClose = (dialog) => {
                    var model = $parse(attrs.showDialog);
                    model.assign(scope, false);
                    scope.$digest();
                };
            }, 0);

            scope.$watch(attrs.showDialog, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    e1.open();
                }
                else {
                    e1.close();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```